# Go to the specific tab when backed from a screen

Tags: codenameone

How can I go to a specific tab when backed from a screen? Lets say I am in newForm screen and when I touch the back button, I'll go to Home screen. There are 4 tabs in homeScreen and I want to go to 3rd tab as soon as I've backed to home.

Home class

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
tabs.addTab("Home", icon, homeContainer);
tabs.addTab("Home1", icon1, home1Container);
tabs.addTab("Home2", icon2, home2Container);
tabs.addTab("Home3", icon3, home3Container);

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);

Button newForm = new Button("New Form");
newForm.addActionListener(e=>{
    new NewForm(res).show();
});
```

NewForm class:

```
 Command back = new Command("") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        new Home(res).show();
    }
 };
 .setBackCommand(back);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping an instance of the `Home` form and just using `Home.getInstance().showBack()`. This will mean that the last selected tab would remain "as is".

If you want to select a specific index use: `tabs.setSelectedIndex(idx, false)`.

Notice that the index starts at 0.