# How to go back to calling Tab from Screen on Kotlin Compose

Tags: tabs, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know how to go back to the Tab that called the new Screen in a Compose environment.

The application has a long stack of navigation screens.  In one of the Screens I have Three Tabs. In tow of them I call a child Screen.  Is the same screen but with a parameter to modify the functionality of the screen according to the Tab that call it. When going back it returns to the parent screen as expected but to the first Tab. But I wish to know how to return to the Tab that called he child screen.

I tried to save the state/tab index before and after the child navigation in the Click event into another state variable (preIndex) to reasigned it to the tabindex but did not work. I guess the preIndex also lost the saved state.

There is a suggestion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444844/go-to-the-specific-tab-when-backed-from-a-screen) but I think does not apply to my case.

This is the relevant code:

```
 var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

 val tabs = listOf("Warranty", "Manufacturer", "Provider")

 Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
        //.verticalScroll(scrollState)

) {

    Text(text = "Add Warranty", fontSize = 22.sp)

    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                selected = tabIndex == index,
                onClick = { tabIndex = index }
            )
        }
    }
    when (tabIndex) {
        0 -> {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)

            ) {

                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = insn,
                    onValueChange = { enteredText ->
                        insn = enteredText
                    },
                    label = { Text(text = "Serial Number") },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter Serial Number") }
                )

                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = indescription,
                    onValueChange = { enteredText ->
                        indescription = enteredText
                    },
                    label = { Text(text = "Description") },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter Descrption") }
                )

            }
        }

        1 -> {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {

                Combobox(
                    inmanufacturer,
                    getOnlyManufacturers(viewModel),
                    "Manufacturer",
                    "Enter Manufacturer"
                )
                
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(4.dp))

                Button(
                    onClick = { navController.navigate("InsertScreenProvider/${false}") },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

                ) {
                    Text(text = "Insert Manufacturer")
                }

            }

            MyDate(instartdateM, btnName = "Manf. Warr. Start Date", "M. W. Start Date")

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(4.dp))

            MyDate(inenddateM, btnName = "Manf. Warr. End Date", "M. W. End Date", true)
        }
//Another tab code
     }
```

The Tabs are inside another Screen not below the onCreate.